# changing primary ID column type from uniqueiIdentifier to nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design, database-schema

I have a huge database in SQL Server with complex dependency, lots of stored procedures and complex views.

Now based on business requirements, I have to change the column data type from `uniqueidentifier`to `nvarchar`.

Can I change column data type to `nvarchar` if the column is the primary key of the table?

Can I do that if the primary key column is used as foreign key in another table?

Comment: Well you can do that, but its not advisable. Because then you might have to update in all dependent table. I'd suggest to first do it in dummy DB and then apply it in your development DB and then do some CRUD operation using your SP to test.

Comment: Not directly - you'd have to first **drop** all the referencing FK constraints, then change your datatype in the parent table, change the datatype for all referencing foreign keys, and then re-create the primary key constraint again - and this *for each table* ...

Comment: @marc_s +1 . ya that will be the way. Better I try to change data to uniqueidentifier and push to tables.

Comment: Neither `uniqueidentifier` nor `nvarchar` make for very good and powerful primary keys - both are not well suited for that task. If you are changing, I'd **strongly** recommend going to a `INT` or `BIGINT` instead of `nvarchar` ....

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that.

The errors you will get when trying so will be

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN  failed because one or more objects access this column.

The dependencies are the primary key of the table created on the column and the foreign key created on another table referencing to this column.

Excerpts from `MSDN` -

1. A FOREIGN KEY constraint specified at the column level can list only one reference column. This column must have the same data type as the column on which the constraint is defined.
2. A FOREIGN KEY constraint specified at the table level must have the same   number of reference columns as the number of columns in the constraint column list. The data type of each reference column must also be the same as the   corresponding column in the column list.